# Wrap whole search hit word in Algolia

Tags: algolia

Is there a way to have Algolia wrap the entire word that is highlighted in search hits? Because right now it may cause the word to break in two when being rendered. As an example, say I've searched for the word «*example*», and then I get a result on a title that is: «*There are many good examples for how to do this*». The HTML for this would then be `<div>There are many good <em>example</em>s for how to do this</div>`, which, given a narrow element could be rendered like this:

```
There are many good example
s for how to do this
```

Is there even a setting for this, or would I have to regex/voodoo this?

**Edit:** I found that the reason the word breaks is because I've set `em {display:inline-block}`, which I need for styling purposes. I could work around that, but it would be cleaner to just have the highlighted word wrapped in some way, eg: `<span><em>example</em>s</span>`

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a css issue related to [`word-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break), inline elements shouldn't break the flow, see this pen: https://codepen.io/Haroenv/pen/zEdyZb

```css
div {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.broken {
  word-break: break-all;
}

.keep {
  word-break: keep-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="normal">There are many good <em>example</em>s for how to do this</div>
<div class="broken">There are many good <em>example</em>s for how to do this</div>
<div class="keep">There are many good <em>example</em>s for how to do this</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, after playing around with some exampled, I found that the reason it breaks is because of my CSS. I've updated my question with the CSS. I also found a work-around for what I needed, but as I included in my edit, it would still be nice with a wrapper for the whole word.

Comment: That's how inline-block behaves, there's no Algolia option to wrap the word, you'll have to do it yourself with some regex (as you suggested) if that's really needed